# IO-performing functions called in same statement: Undefined or unspecified?

Tags: c++

I am starting to learn C++ from C++ Primer (5th edition).  Working through the chapter on expressions, I came up with an example program that has me wondering:

```
int f1()
{
    cout << "f1\n";
    return 1;
}

int f2()
{
    cout << "f2\n";
    return 2;
}

int main() {
    int i = f1() + f2();
    return 0;
}
```

I am unsure whether this program invokes undefined or merely unspecified behavior.  I know that the order in which functions `f1` and `f2` are called is unspecified.  Each function writes to standard output as a side effect, so at best, the order in which the lines are printed is unspecified.  At worst, this invokes undefined behavior.

I know the answer lies somewhere in the C++ standard, but it is quite technical for my current level of understanding.  A gentler explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is unspecified behaviour. In C++03 language, there is a sequence point before and after each function call. C++11 language says the same thing with different terminology.

Comment: There is, however, a proposal to specify the order of evaluation. But there's no undefined behaviour; anything in the function will be sequenced properly in relation to anything in the other function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### [Unspecified Behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)
>
> The behavior of the program varies between implementations and the conforming implementation is not required to document the effects of each behavior. For example, **order of evaluation**, whether identical string literals are distinct, the amount of array allocation overhead, etc. Each unspecified behavior results in one of a set of valid results.
>
> ### [Order of Evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)
>
> [T]here is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in C++. This is not to be confused with left-to-right and right-to-left associativity of operators: the expression f1() + f2() + f3() is parsed as (f1() + f2()) + f3() due to left-to-right associativity of operator+, but **the function call to f3 may be evaluated first, last, or between f1() or f2() at run time.**

If order is important, you do

```
int a = f1();
int b = f2();
int i = a + b;
```

If order isn't important, then the code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The topic of "undefined behavior" is quite the nuisance on the site. For quite a while, there were many questions asking "Is this undefined behavior?" and answerers rushing to say "yes" when it actually wasn't the case. I believe what you're thinking of are cases like this:

> The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced
>   before the value computation of the result of the operator. If a side
>   effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another
>   side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the
>   value of the same scalar object, and they are not potentially
>   concurrent (1.10), the behavior is undefined.
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> void f(int, int);
> void g(int i, int* v) {
>   i = v[i++];        // the behavior is undefined
>   i = 7, i++, i++;   // i becomes 9
>
>   i = i++ + 1;       // the behavior is undefined
>   i = i + 1;         // the value of i is incremented
>
>   f(i = -1, i = -1); // the behavior is undefined
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Both modifying an object and calling a library I/O function are side effects. Other than that, there is no relation whatsoever that implies your example has undefined behavior.

The other problem I have are answerers who would rather dump a bunch of nice-sounding standardese that is more difficult to parse than the human-friendly version. As a result, people tend to miss the bigger picture. Here is an example:

> §1.9/15 For each function invocation *F* , for every evaluation *A*
>   that occurs within *F* and every evaluation *B* that does not occur
>   within *F* but is evaluated on the same thread and as part of the same
>   signal handler (if any), either *A* is sequenced before *B* or *B* is
>   sequenced before *A*.

Translation: If *A* and *B* would not otherwise be sequenced, then they are indeterminately sequenced. By definition, *indeterminately sequenced* means they can occur in **any order** but may not overlap.

Furthermore, in inexact terms, the operands of the `+` operator are unsequenced. So `+` does not represent a "sequence point". Therefore, `f1()` and `f2()` are indeterminately sequenced and you can infer that it's unspecified behavior.

TL;DR: Forget the standard, focus on learning the language. You get too bogged down into details and you lose sight of the bigger picture and confuse things. [Here's a human-friendly treatise on the subject](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

Comment: The human-friendly version is fine as long as it's accompanied by _evidence_, and there's no authoritative source of evidence beyond the standard. We have enough unattributed, unsourced information on Stack Overflow misleading a whole generation of programmers to write dangerously broken code. So I don't think your rant about correct answers in the [tag:c++] tag is valid; it's certainly not constructive.